# How can you scale up css font-size as the container maintains aspect ratio?

Tags: css, fonts, scale, font-size, aspect-ratio

Let's say I have an element:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 209px;
  height: 323px;
}

.container .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

**WITHOUT using any sort of variable** `font-size` **unit**, if the `.container` element scales up to `528px` by `816px` (so it has the exact same aspect ratio), what is the multiply factor so the text is relatively the same size when the parent scales up? The `top` and `left` are easy to re-calculate, but I'm not sure about fonts. And I guess the `font-family` might effect the scale factor right?

**UPDATE**

It seems for my case that whatever the `font-size`, that is the height of the text element. I saw another SO post (forgot the link) going in to great detail about a number of variables (`font-size`, `line-height`, `vertical-align`, etc.) that determine the height of the text element and that a certain combination will allow `font-size` and `height` to be equal. Knowing this, scaling the `font-size` becomes trivial.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is not to use font-size as hard coded pixels and to instead just use `rem`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

[https://medium.com/code-better/css-units-for-font-size-px-em-rem-79f7e592bb97#:~:text=rem%20values%20are%20relative%20to,the%20browser%20(usually%2016px)](https://medium.com/code-better/css-units-for-font-size-px-em-rem-79f7e592bb97#:%7E:text=rem%20values%20are%20relative%20to,the%20browser%20(usually%2016px)).